# Create a zip with files from an AWS S3 path

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

Is there a way to provide a single URL for a user to download all the content from an S3 path?

Otherwise, is there a way to create a zip with all files found on an S3 path recursively?

ie. `my-bucket/media/123/*`

Each path usually has 1K+ images and 10+ videos.

Comment: You can sync content using the awscli, for example: aws s3 sync s3://mybucket/path1/path2/ .

Answer (score 3):

There's no built-in way. You have to download all files, compact them "locally", re-upload it, and then you'll have a single URL for download.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned before, there's no built-in way to do it. But from another hand, you don't need to download and upload back your files. You could create a serverless solution in the same AWS region/location.

You could implement it in different ways:

- [**API Gateway + Lambda Function**](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-create-api-as-simple-proxy-for-lambda.html)

In this case, you will trigger your lambda function via API Gateway. Lambda function will create an archive from your bucket's files and upload the result back to S3. Lambda function will return URL to this archive***. 
**Drawbacks of this way**: Lambda can't execute more than 5 min and if you have too many files, it will not have enough time to process them. Be aware, that S3 max file size is 5 terabytes. The largest object that can be uploaded in a single PUT is 5 gigabytes. For objects larger than 100 megabytes, you should consider using the Multipart Upload capability.
Example: [Full guide to developing REST API’s with AWS API Gateway and AWS Lambda](https://blog.sourcerer.io/full-guide-to-developing-rest-apis-with-aws-api-gateway-and-aws-lambda-d254729d6992)

- [**Step Function**](https://aws.amazon.com/step-functions/getting-started/) (API Gateway + Lambda Function that calls Step Function)

5 min should be enough to create an archive, but if you are going to do some preprocessing I recommend you to use Step Function. SF has the limitation with the maximum number of registered activities/states and request size (you can't pass you archive in a request) but it is easy to avoid it (if you take it to consideration during designing). Check out more [there](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/limits.html).

Personally, I am using both ways for different cases.

*** It is bad practice - give to user path to your real file on S3. It is better to use [CloudFront CDN](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/). CloudFront allows you to control the lifetime of URL and provide different ways of security and restrictions.

Comment: Lambda also has a 512 MB limit on /tmp diskspace so unless you use a clever  in/out streaming solution, you will not be able to archive all that much data.

Comment: @jarmod good point. I guess that Step Function could help with this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no single call you can make to s3 to download as a .zip. You would have to create a service recursively download all of the objects and compress them. It is important to keep in mind the size limit of your S3 objects though. The limit is [5TB per object](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-s3-object-size-limit/). You will want to add a check to verify the size of the .zip before re-upload.